# How to display an icon on JOptionPane.showInputDialog() in Java?

Tags: java, swing

The following segment of code shows `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` method. It works fine, Now I want to display a custom icon on it. I currently left it **null** as shown below.

```
String operatingSystem = System.getProperty("os.name");
Object o[] = {"Turn Off", "Restart", "Stand By", "Log Off"};
Frame frame = new Frame(operatingSystem);

Object selectedValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, 
    "What would you like to do with the system?", "Select a task", 
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, o, o[0]);   //<---- Here it is.
```

How can an icon be displayed on it replacing **null**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Swing provides a particularly useful implementation of the Icon interface: [ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html), which paints an icon from a GIF, JPEG, or PNG image.

Here is a tutorial for you : [How to Use Icons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)

When youre done creating the icon, simply replace the `null` with your [Icon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Icon.html). Done!